# AWS Elastic BeanStalk nodejs Deployment error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

I am stuck in a very weird issue from the last two days. I am trying to deploy my webpack nodejs app on AWS elastic beanstalk. The **Environment Health** changes from **OK** to **Degraded**. I have deployed it many times before but no such issue occurred. First of all, see the logs:

**/var/log/eb-activity.log**

> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action node-install 
>   Activity execution failed, because: +
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
>
> npm ERR! path
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp
>   npm ERR! code EEXIST   npm ERR! Refusing to delete
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp:
>   is outside
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
>   and not a link
>
> npm ERR! File exists:
>   /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp
>   npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
>        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:   npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2018-09-18T05_49_17_967Z-debug.log   Running npm
>   install: 
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/bin/npm
>   Setting npm config jobs to 1   npm config jobs set to 1   Running npm
>   with --production flag   Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for
>   more details.   UTC 2018/09/18 05:49:17 cannot find application npm
>   debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 
>        Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in 
>         main()
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
>         node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
>         self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
>         raise e   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v8.9.3-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

Now the error is of some **node-gyp** module and trust me I haven't heard it before. I am trying for a solution so that I can continue my work because this is really an embarrassing situation for me in front of my boss. Your help can get me out of this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Duda Yes, I solved it. It was a **Node Module** issue. I degraded the version of that specific module and it works!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problems with various node modules. It was a simple toy project where I created the initial NodeJs express project using `express init`.

I found various posts about adding a file to the .ebextensions folder and ended up with this version:

Create a file called `01_delete_node_modules.config` in the .ebextensions folder and add the following content:

```yaml
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/49_delete_node_modules.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo rm -rf /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules
```

Cudos to this blog post by Josh Harris:
https://medium.com/@jharris.sf/npm-rebuild-elastic-beanstalk-and-permissions-be1c6fceba9a

Comment: Thank you!  Didn't know you could do that, very helpful.  With Heroku, 'magic scripts' like this are not required by default.  However I'm thankful to try out Beanstalk thanks to helpful scripts like this.