# AWS Elastic Beanstalk | Error:Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Reactjs/Firebase application (made using a material UI template), but when I create the new environment by uploading the code, it shows the following errors:

[image]

The error which is shown in the log file:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! grpc@1.23.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.23.3 install script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2020-02-03T17_23_00_028Z-debug.log
  Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
  Setting npm config jobs to 1
  npm config jobs set to 1
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  UTC 2020/02/03 17:23:00 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I tried rebuilding the environment several times, but the same error is shown.

What could be the reason for the error and what can I try to fix it?

I am using node version 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

`cannot find application npm debug log`

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380024/aws-elastic-beanstalk-nodejs-deployment-error)